# TikZ: Inexplicable whitespace when predefining shapes

Tags: tikz-pgf, white-space

Assumed we want to predefine some shapes for later usage in a `TikZ`-picture.

---

**Minimum Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \def\testone#1#2{
        \begin{scope}[shift={#1}, rotate=#2]
            \draw(0,0) rectangle (2,1);
        \end{scope}}

    \def\testtwo#1#2{
        \begin{scope}[shift={#1}, rotate=#2]
            \draw(0,0) rectangle (2,1);
        \end{scope}}

    \def\testthree#1#2{
        \begin{scope}[shift={#1}, rotate=#2]
            \draw(0,0) rectangle (2,1);
        \end{scope}}

    \def\testfour#1#2{
        \begin{scope}[shift={#1}, rotate=#2]
            \draw(0,0) rectangle (2,1);
        \end{scope}}

    \def\testfive#1#2{
        \begin{scope}[shift={#1}, rotate=#2]
            \draw(0,0) rectangle (2,1);
        \end{scope}}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \testone{(0,0)}{0};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot of the result]

---

**Description of the issue:**

As you can see, there is a lot of whitespace on the left side of the draw. It seems that each `\def\figure` causes a little shift to the right which in summary produces this big one.

Where does this undesirable space come from? How can I avoid it?

Comment: I just add a `f` to your question. It is a crucial `f`.

Comment: Btw you should really use `pic` for this

Comment: @JouleV: Thanks a lot! Funnily, writing `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}` also prevents this whitespace. What is the reason to better use `pic`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not coming from the Ti*k*Z environment itself. For example, this code works fine:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

    \def\testone#1#2{
        \begin{scope}[shift={#1}, rotate=#2]
            \draw(0,0) rectangle (2,1);
        \end{scope}}

    \def\testtwo#1#2{
        \begin{scope}[shift={#1}, rotate=#2]
            \draw(0,0) rectangle (2,1);
        \end{scope}}

    \def\testthree#1#2{
        \begin{scope}[shift={#1}, rotate=#2]
            \draw(0,0) rectangle (2,1);
        \end{scope}}

    \def\testfour#1#2{
        \begin{scope}[shift={#1}, rotate=#2]
            \draw(0,0) rectangle (2,1);
        \end{scope}}

    \def\testfive#1#2{
        \begin{scope}[shift={#1}, rotate=#2]
            \draw(0,0) rectangle (2,1);
        \end{scope}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \testone{(0,0)}{0};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In other words, the blank lines are producing line breaks or spaces, which are included in the `standalone` PDF output.

What I recommend here is not to define a command, but a Ti*k*Z `pic`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{
    myrectangle/.pic={
        \begin{scope}[rotate=#1]
            \draw (0,0) rectangle (2,1);
        \end{scope}
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic at (0,0) {myrectangle=0};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```